# Scraping Noise While Driving Noticed Brake Clip Touching Rotor

Tags: brakes, squeaking

I was hearing a squeal noise while driving at low speeds and thought it was the brake pad indicator. My 2011 Tahoe has 130k miles and I've not yet changed the pads.

When I took the pads off I noticed the brake **clip** bent on one side and touching the rotor. I don't think it was the wear indicator. I replaced the front pads and clips and no more noise. Is this something I should think any more about? Was it just bad luck that the clip bent and not even necessarily wear? There was still some pad material left on both pads. If it works the way I expect, the indicator was not exposed  to the rotor yet as the pad level was slightly higher than the indicator.

Comment: If it's been a long time since a brake service you ought to check the thickness of your rotors as they wear too.  If they are below manufacturer tolerance they need to be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you did the job right. The clip may have been dislodged by a stone at some point.